# How to use v-data-table-header vuetify props in vue 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Good afternoon, can someone tell me how to access v-data-table-header props from vuetify? i dont know how to access this (mobile, headers, or anything).

[image: Screenshow]

Answer (score 0):

You just use props in component.

```
<v-data-table-header
  checkbox-color="#000"
  ...
>
  Hi
</v-data-table-header>
```

Comment: ohhh i think it must use with v-slot..
thank you very much bro

Answer (score 0):

you should use v-slot to access those.

```
<template v-slot:header>
    <v-data-table-header> </v-data-table-header>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `header-props`

```
<v-data-table
    :header-props="headerProps"
>
</v-data-table>
...

data: () => ({
    headerProps: {
        sortIcon: 'mdi-menu-up',
    },
}),
```